# How to get data into array in angularJS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Here I have shared plunker link. please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```html
<a href="https://plnkr.co/edit/3VryaPGtgPRD6Nn8zx7v">Plunker link is here</a>
```

Comment: `ng-value="{{Item}}"`. change to `ng-value="{{Item.price}}"` or `ng-value="{{Item.qty}}"` or `ng-value="{{Item.name}}"`

Comment: But I have lot of fields. I want to store all values at once

Comment: AngularJS ng-model Directive. Maybe help for u.

Comment: Explain your question. Do you want to save new changes in the data field or do you want to create the item newly in the data array?

Comment: yes save new changes in data fields.

Comment: Unfortunately, poor quality Questions such as this which offer no content and expect readers to navigate to a 3rd party website for more context are not generally well received here, and tend to lead to negative responses or equally low quality Answers.  It is much better to include a [mcve] **in the question body**.

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.Items = [
    {'id':1,'name':'Apple','price':100,'qty':1},
    {'id':2,'name':'Coconut','price':20,'qty':1}
  ];
  $scope.proceed = function(){
    data=$scope.Items;
    alert(data);
  };
});
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller='appController'>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form >
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>QTY</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat='Item in Items'>
        <td>{{Item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{Item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{Item.price}}</td>
        <td>{{Item.qty}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-init="{{Item.SubTotal = Item.price * Item.qty}}" name="Item.SubTotal" ng-model="Item.SubTotal" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table><br>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="proceed()" />
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

check updated plunker link, you can update object, newly updated object will be appended to table.

---

[updated plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/bxRf2ctaFZydrgpx)

Comment: While this probably solves the problem, it suffers from the same problem the question itself does.  Questions and/or answers without actual content are not useful, since they require navigating to a 3rd party site in order to actually piece together what is going on.  This is *troublesome* when the links work, but can make the content *completely useless* if the link changes or the content is removed from the 3rd party website.  Instead, you should include a [mcve] **in the body itself**.